# Load child entity on the fetch of the Parent entity EFCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor, ef-core-3.0

I have the below model. What is the better way to load the parent entity with child entity at the time of fetching from the DB with find method?

**Parent Entity:**

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

**Child Entity:**

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstLine { get; set; }

    public string SecondLine { get; set; }

    public string Province { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I try to fetch the data using the Find method I got the address entity null, but when I check in the DB data exist for that ID in Child table too.

```
referenceContext.Clients.Find(client.Id);
```

Is there a way to overcome this? When I fetch the parent object and at the same time the value of the child entity is also loaded with the parent.

Notes: As of now, if I used the `Include(i => i.Address)` then, and then, only I am able to load the child entity.

I already use the Include but is there any other option exist to load child entity if I get the parent entity.

```
referenceContext.Clients.Where(c => c.IsActive.Equals(true))
                        .Include(i => i.Address).ToList();
```

[image: DB Deatils]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you said:

> *Notes: As of now, if I used the **Include(i => i.Address)** then, and then, only I am able to load the child entity.*

**Yes! this is the best way to load related data in EF Core.**

You further said:

> *I already use the Include but is there any other option exist to load child entity if I get the parent entity.*

Yes! There is! That is called [Lazy loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading). To enable lazy loading you have to make the navigation property ***virtual*** as follows:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; } // <-- Here it is
}
```

And you have to register your `DbConext` as follows:

```
services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(
    b => b.UseLazyLoadingProxies() // <-- Here is it is
          .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString));
```

`UseLazyLoadingProxies()` method is available in the  [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies/) nuget package.

***Note: You cannot disable lazy loading for a certain query. So using [Eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading) is the best way to load related data in EF Core.***

Answer (score 6):

In EF, there is a concept called `Eager Loading` using `.Include`.

MS Docs - [Loading Related Data - EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DMdSWk)

```
using MyContext context = new MyContext();

IList<Client> clients =
    context.Clients
        .Include(c => c.Address)
        .Where(c => c.LastName == "patel")
        .ToList();
```

Comment: I forgot to add this: using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Include()](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/eager-loading-in-entity-framework.aspx)

**Linq query**

```
using (var context = new DBEntities())
{
   var result = (from c in context.Client.Include("Address")
            where c.IsActive
            select c).ToList();
}
```

**Lambda Expression**

```
using (var context = new DBEntities())
{
   var result = context.Client.Include(p => p.Address).Where(c => c.IsActive).ToList();
}
```